# Precisely scheduling sound in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, avaudioplayer, audioqueueservices

I'm working on an iOS7-only app that needs to display a clock complete with ticking sound. I've used a NSTimer of 1s and I use AVAudioPlayer to play the tick sound every second.

Unfortunately, there's something slightly off with the timing. I've measured that timer is off by between 2 and 22 thousands of a second, which you wouldn't think would matter a great deal, but the lag creates a nail biting tension.. kind of like a heart flutter :-)

I've looked around a bit but it sounds like using audio queue services is the only way to go.. and I really don't fancy delving into the depths of that particular framework again.

My question: Is there some other way of getting precisely scheduled sound events in iOS 7 and failing that is there a decent wrapper framework for audio queue services available somewhere? Or better still is there a way of more precisely scheduling NSTimers?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `dispatch_after`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any of `NSTimer`, `libdispatch`, or spawning a thread that sleeps for the tick duration rely on the underlying thread getting scheduled in time. The kernel provides no guarantee of this, and it is not surprising that the you observe timing jitter; the latency you observe looks reasonable.

`NSTimer` running on the main thread is likely to perform worst of these as you are also contending against other events delivered through it.

I think your options here are either to use audio queue services,  a real-time thread to schedule the events with AVAudioPlayer, or render the audio yourself to a `remoteIO` unit.

I don't think AVPlayer provides any particular guarantees about timing either.

Comment: Another "solution" would be to play a looping 60 second segment or so of the ticks which would guarantee the time between the ticks, but not sync this with the seconds on the clock changing".

Comment: @FrankR Yes. It would need to be separate real-time thread.  Worth noting that CoreAudio's render callbacks always are from a RT Thread -  so scheduling events on the back of these is one option.

As for AVAudioPlayer - anybody's guess.  No guarantees that if it were thread safe that it's not simply posting work to a dispatch queue itself.

Comment: @FrankR. Your *other solution* has one big drawback: how to synchronise it with the clock.  I can't see how you can possibly do this other than hope you get it right the first time.  Guess at least the ticks are regular, and perhaps the user won't notice that they're perhaps 20ms out. 

It has the minor drawback that audio is output on different and possibly asynchronous clock to that of the system.